# Matlab transformation from cell array to matrix array

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, for-loop

I built a script (from different scripts of my work group) to read out data from a folder. The problem is at the end I get a data array with 1x49 cell. I need the data in a matrix array for a waterfall plot with matlab.

The final matrix I need has in the first column the variable 'wave' and from column 2 to i ( the number of cells in my data array) the data from my data array.

I don't know how to get into the single array fields.

This is what I wrote to get the data in the array:

```
clc;clear;      
selpath = uigetdir; 
filelist = dir(selpath);  
filelist = {filelist.name};
filter = cellfun(@(u) contains(u, '.txt'),filelist);    

data = []; 
for i = 1:numel(filelist)   
    filename = filelist{i};
    filename = [selpath '/' filename];
    delimiter = '\t';

    formatSpec = '%q%q%q%q%q%q%q%[^\n\r]';
    fileID = fopen(filename,'r');
    dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'TextType', 'string',  'ReturnOnError', false);
    fclose(fileID);
    tmp_data =(dataArray{1});
    data{i} = tmp_data; 
 end
```

Is there any clever way to enter the loop? Or do I need a new loop to transform it?

I tried it with:
`data = cell2mat(data)`

But this does not transform my data.

Edit: This is how one of my files look:

```
Data from cystein_21101181_01.txt Node

Date: Thu Apr 08 12:37:33 CEST 2021
User: admin
Spectrometer: 211-0118
Scans to average: 16
cleanPeaks enabled: false
laserRefSpectrum enabled: true
Raster (0) enable: true
Integration Time (sec): 1.000000E0
XAxis mode: Raman Shifts
Number of Pixels in Spectrum: 1152
>>>>>Begin Spectral Data<<<<<
201.679 783.5
203.772 813.94
205.865 825.62
207.956 843
210.046 860.44
212.135 882.44
214.223 900.25
216.311 912.31
```

I just save them as `.txt` files in one folder. Select the folder in the script and then the script should import all spectra and put them together in one matrix.

Comment: Do all the `data{i}` have the same dimensions? Why doesn't `cell2mat` work? Why do you create the cell and not a matrix in the first place? Without a minimal reproducible example it is impossible for us to help you.

Comment: just try to do `a=[ dataArray{1} ]` and see if you get the array you want. the `[ ]` brackets will damp the cell array into an array if possible. If you want particular cells you can `[somedata{2:5}] ` etc....

Comment: @MatteoV yes the `data{i}` has all the same dimensions. But when I try it I get this error: CELL2MAT does not support cell arrays containing cell arrays or objects. This is the beginning of my code. Do you need a file I import with the script? I will edit the post and add the content of one of my files. All files look like this, only with different data from spectrometer.

Comment: @bla if I try `a = [dataArray{1}]`I get the first column of my data array. This works. So I detect a mistake I made. So I import always the first column of a file but I also need the second row. Maybe CELL2MAT does not work 'cause there is text in the beginning of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that all your files have the same structure, I think it would be better to use `readtable()`.

```
% The start is the same as before
clc;clear;      
selpath = uigetdir; 
filelist = dir(selpath);
filelist = {filelist.name};
filter = cellfun(@(u) contains(u, '.txt'),filelist);    

data = []; 

% Initialize the settings to read your files
opts = delimitedTextImportOptions("NumVariables", 2);
opts.DataLines = [14, Inf]; % Skip the first 13 header lines
opts.Delimiter = " "; % data columns are delimited by spaces
opts.VariableTypes = ["double", "double"]; % specify the variable type for your each columns
opts.ExtraColumnsRule = "ignore"; % ignore any other column
opts.EmptyLineRule = "read"; % read lines even if they're empty
opts.ConsecutiveDelimitersRule = "join"; % treat multiple spaces as only one delimiter
opts.LeadingDelimitersRule = "ignore"; % ignore leading spaces

% Now loop through your files
for i = 1:numel(filelist)
    filename = filelist{i};
    filename = [selpath '/' filename];

    % Read the file and append the data to your array
    data = [data; table2array(readtable(filename, opts))];
    % or maybe? unsure what your wanted:
    % data{i} = table2array(readtable(filename, opts));
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried it but in my final matrix I just get NaN.

Comment: This code worked for me with the small example that you provided. If you get NaNs only, I suspect it might be because the structure of your actual files might be different somehow, and in that case some setting should be modified. Can you try applying the code to the small example file and check if it it works on that?